# Nginx faking ip address with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I need a proxied request appear as if it came from the localhost. I tried following `nginx` config:

```
proxy_set_header  Host            "127.0.0.1";
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       "127.0.0.1";
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For "127.0.0.1";

proxy_read_timeout 10m;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp/websocket;
```

However underlying backend is still capable to recognize, that request is not local:

> STOMP login failed - access_refused (user must access over loopback)

Comment: `Host` should contain port number.

Comment: And there should be no `X-Real-IP`, `X-Forwarded-For` headers, as they clearly indicates that request is proxied. Real browser pointed to `localhost` would never send these headers.

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you've suggested - added port component and removed extra headers - no joy unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one Nginx header, [proxy_bind](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_bind)

```
proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
```

Here's the documentation for the effect of what this does:

*Makes outgoing connections to a proxied server originate from the specified local IP address*

That sounds like exactly what you need. The other headers you set to 127.0.0.1 may not be required.

Comment: `lo` is bound to `inet 127.0.0.1/8` for sure. Underlying server daemon is `RabbitMQ`. Rabbit allows remote connections with a different username, so it's not worth trying to understand its internals. However I thought it would be a good exercise to find out how to mask clients ip address with `nginx`, as I thought that when nginx is proxying requests, receiving party sees them as coming from the local host by default. Apparently my assumptions were fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I think my first answer was wrong. See updated answer.

Comment: It indeed does what it says it can do. Thanks for digging it up!